# OpenCL on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: opencl, visual-studio-2017

I need to work with OpenCL (intel) for a university program.
I decided to develop on my laptop with Visual Studio (2017 RC) while the target device will be an external board yet to be defined.

Yesterday I downloaded the Intel OpenCL SDK on my old laptop with VS2012 and it worked, as in I could see OpenCL project template in VS.

Today I tried to do the same thing with my new PC, installation goes ok but I cannot see the OpenCL template in VS (I see all others).
I get a warning that my CPU (4th gen i7) is not supported by OpenCL, this shouldn't be a problem though as it will not be target.

Notice that I have installed Visual Studio on a secondary drive, although it took some space on the main drive as well.

Thank you!

Comment: The installer may have some sort of file (.ini or .xml) which lists the platforms it can be installed on. You can edit that file. If the installer is just one file, you can probably open it as if it is a zip file and get to the relevant file.

Comment: Thank you
I have looked for it but couldn't find any such file of sort.

Comment: I have found though that the SDK is only supported for VS2015 and 2013 so I have reverted to 2015